# PHP DBlib PDO Issue

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to an MSSQL server through php but my pdo connection is giving me a hard time and errors that I don't really understand. The code I pasted below was working just fine a week ago and all of a sudden it just stopped without anyone changing anything. I can still connect to the server and run queries directly from the command line but I'm not having the same luck within php.
Anyone see something that I am missing? I spent too much time on this already and it seems like I'm running in circles.

**First, this is the error I am getting from my PDOException**

```
SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0)
```

**Part of my Mssql()**

```
 private function __construct() {
        try{
           $this->_pdo = new PDO('dblib:host=' . Config::get('prod/host') . ':'. Config::get('prod/port') .';dbname=' . Config::get('prod/db'),Config::get('prod/username'), Config::get('prod/password'));
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        // Already an instance of this? Return, if not, create.
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new Mssql();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    } //...This function is working and directs to __construct()
```

**How I am calling it**

```
/*Some random php file*/
function getClients(){
    $conn = Mssql::getInstance();
//.....
```

And my init.php

```
//...
prod' => array(
        'host'      => 'xxxxxxx',
        'port'      => '1433',
        'username'  => 'xxxxxxx',
        'password'  => 'xxxxxx',
        'db'        => 'xxxxxxx'
    ),
//.....
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518175/pdoexception-with-message-sqlstate-null-severity-0 ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I do have the correct string as that guys accepted answer and still is not working.

Comment: debugging: Is it a PDO issue? I would setup a PHP script with a hard coded DSN username and password. So, can you connect to any user on any MSSQL database using PDO? If not then something has changed with the PHP / PDO. If yes then setup a new user on the  database in question and get that connection working. Then redo the settings for the offending user/password and get that working?

Comment: The "SQLSTATE[]" part comes from the server, which makes me suspect that your code is connecting OK, but something isn't right on the server side. I'd suggest updating your post so it includes more (all would be preferable) of your Mssql class, as well as the SQL that you're sending to the server.

Comment: @RyanVincent If I try it this way $connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database";
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass); it works...

Comment: Not sure that the `odbc` driver uses `dblib`. I suspect not. However, you know that PHP /  PDO works which is good?. Has something changed with `dblib`?

Comment: @RyanVincent nothing changed as far as I know. We are checking the server configuration now to see if an update messed up something we didn't see before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed from using dblib to odbc and the code in my class changed to this:

```
 private function __construct() {
        putenv('ODBCSYSINI=/etc');
        putenv('ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini');
        $username = "xxxx";
        $password = "xxxx";
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO("odbc:production","$username","$password");
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {                
            die($exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Good find. Just a side note, [you should never catch errors to report them.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)

Comment: We removed the echo parts after I posted my answer :)

Comment: Also the username and password can be transferred directly in odbc.ini as far as I remember

Comment: But with `die()` you're doing practically the same. **It is `try` and `catch` that should be actually removed.**

Comment: @RyanVincent I will in a day when I'm allowed :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks for the article!! Need to make a few changes :)